# pd.read_clipboard() change the output if I copied something new

Tags: pandas, clipboard

When I use `'df = pd.read_clipboard()'`, sometimes I have to restart the kernal, the laptop, or even copy something new; how to make sure the cell will still keep the original output, if I had to re-run it again please?
Or how to go around this please?
Thank you :-)

I have 3 tables in one excel sheet, used `df = pd.read_clipboard()`, to call the first table as df, the same for the other two tables as df1 & df2.
But each time I had to re-run any cell, they just retrieve the last copied thing in the clipboard.

Comment: how big is the table you are trying to copy&paste? Did you try a smaller one - to see if this is a matter of size?

Comment: Very small tables 10 * 5.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help without a sample of the data, however, try this and let me know:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')
```